# Subtracting values based on another Column FID

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

As per attached JPG, i want to subtract values upper to lower row as per shown.
But when "ORIG_FID" change, then its start from first value and ends up where FID values are same. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1-B2,"")
```

[image]